# Postgis Error when upgrading to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgis, postgresql-9.3

My team and I are going through a maintenance phase currently, and I've been busy upgrading everything. Last week I moved the team from PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.3 and PostGIS 1.5 to 2.1 which all went smoothly. Yesterday, the Rails team submitted a Rails 4 upgrade pull request that our CI swiftly rejected. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

When attempting to create a new test database, I receive the following Rails error:

```
PG::RaiseException: ERROR:  PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall it first : CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA public
```

Some specs:

- Debian 7 Wheezy
- PostgreSQL 9.3
- PostGIS 2.1
- Ruby 2.1.0
- Rails 4

My PostgreSQL / PostGIS installation steps:

```
sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update -y

apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1

sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER xxadmin WITH PASSWORD 'xxpass';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER xxadmin WITH SUPERUSER;"

sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database template_postgis with template = template1;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE where datname = 'template_postgis';"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis--2.1.2.sql
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO xxadmin;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO xxadmin;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "VACUUM FREEZE;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER DATABASE template_postgis OWNER TO xxadmin;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "ALTER VIEW geography_columns OWNER to xxadmin;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER to xxadmin;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER to xxadmin;"
```

Comment: Why do you need to go through the tedious steps creating `'template_postgis'`? Just make a new database and execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` and that should do it.

Comment: I am less familiar with PostgreSQL. I was under the impression that creating a template was good form, correct or no?

Comment: It was required before 'CREATE EXTENSION' was possible. Now 'CREATE EXTENSION' is considered best practise.

Comment: Yep, `template_postgis` can be left as a forgotten relic of history. Thankfully.

Comment: Thanks fellas. Always a relief when the problem is between keyboard and chair.

Comment: `create extension postgis;` does not create the required tables in the database;

Comment: I found my problem: in `config/database.yml` there was a line `schema_search_path: public.postgis`  which was causing the geo-tables not to be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently a few *different* methods to spatially enable a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS:

1. Using the DDL command [`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions). **Easiest and recommended.**
2. Using [enabler scripts](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db). This method has multiple steps, is useful if you have specific requirements, for example disallowing raster support.
3. Using [a template (e.g. `template_postgis`)](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#templatepostgis) database. This could be useful to setup multiple databases that have similar features. Sometimes `template_postgis` is pre-installed, other times you would need to create this.

Comment: `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` does not create the corresponding tables in the database! OSX Mavericks, Rails 4.1.1 , Ruby 2.1.1, PostgreSQL 9.3.4, PostGIS 2.1.3 

`select postgis_full_version();` and `ST_*` queries return No Function matches.. super annoying

Comment: I found my problem: in config/database.yml there was a line schema_search_path: public.postgis which was causing the geo-tables not to be generated